# Arguements are Valid but Don't Work in C#

Tags: c#, file, function, arguments

I'm making a function that uses a user inputted directory and a passed string to create a .txt with the string in it. Here's my code:

```
private void MakeTheTxt(string theTest)
{
    string fileName = @textBoxDirectory.Text;
    try
    {
        File.WriteAllLines(fileName, theTest);
    }
    catch (DirectoryNotFoundException e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please enter a valid directory.");
    }
}
```

The `WriteAllLines()` function says the arguments are not valid. I looked up the parameters of this function and one of the overloaded definitions is `public static void WriteAllText(string path, string contents);`. I'm giving the function the correct argument types but it isn't working. Any suggestions?

Comment: According to http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealllines(v=vs.110).aspx there are no overloads that take a `string` for the second argument. What documentation are *you* looking at?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no overload of `WriteAllLines` that takes two `string`s.

You probably want to use [`File.WriteAllText`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writealltext(v=vs.110).aspx) which *does* have a `(string path, string contents)` overload.

```
File.WriteAllText(fileName, theTest);
```

Comment: Nice catch on the similarly named function that *does* have the overload he wants.

Comment: Thank you! I just misread the definition, I was actually looking at that function.

Answer (score 1):

The second parameter is supposed to be a string array, and you are passing it a string.

Try something like:

```
File.WriteAllLines(fileName, new[]{theTest});
```